# getting this flutter error in my app on localhost

Tags: flutter

"type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast" I'm getting this error in my flutter app

tried something like using ?? and some other suggestions provided by chatgpt my error is still not getting resolved

Comment: Without a minimal example of your code, it is hard to identify the issue and help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not possible for us to help without the code. Please [edit] to include your code as text. Also include the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you try cast nullable variable/property to non-nullable type. It usually happens when you try decode JSON.
For example if we have a JSON document like this

```
{
    "name": "John",
}
```

and class like this classes:

It's data structure for persons which can have hometown but hometown can be nullable.

```
class Person {
  const Person({
    required this.name,
    this.hometown,
  });

  Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : this(
          name: json['name'],
          hometown: json['hometown'] != null
              ? City.fromJson(json['hometown'] as Map<String, dynamic>)
              : null,
        );

  final String name;
  final City? hometown;
}

class City {
  const City({
    required this.name,
    required this.countryCode,
  });

  City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : this(
          name: json['name'] as String,
          countryCode: json['country_code'] as String,
        );

  final String name;
  final String countryCode;
}
```

Pay your attention to this condition:

```
      hometown: json['hometown'] != null
          ? City.fromJson(json['hometown'] as Map<String, dynamic>)
          : null,
```

Here we check json['hometown'] exists or doesn't and only if it is existed we can create instance of City. You can find the same place in your code and it’s a reason why you have problem that you described.